# olly debugger cannot find referenced text

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I created a very simple c++ console application which compare user entered password with hard-corded one and print corresponding output.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  string password;
  cout << "Enter the password"<<endl;
  getline (cin, password);

 if(password=="123"){

      cout << "correct password" <<endl;
 }else  {
      cout << "incorrect password" <<endl;
 }
  return 0;

}
```

I want to debug and skip a specific line. For that I want to search the `correct password / incorrect password` line. So I tried using "search for all referenced text " option but the problem is there is no such text.

I followed some tutorials where they search for referenced text and find that kind of hard coded lines.

Comment: Shouldn't you disassemble the app first?

Comment: @ForceBru actually i followed some tutorials .they just open the exe file from olly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I tried and it worked for me:

[image]

I compiled the code with onlinecompiler.net, which use `mingw` as far as I know. Here is the [link to the executable](http://www.onlinecompiler.net/upload/tmp/wB5joSlS.exe).

It may be a problem with your compiler, but neither `gcc`/`mingw` nor `cl.exe` are modifying hardcoded strings at compile time.

Also, are you sure that you are doing the search in your program module? (not in the ntdll one for instance)

Comment: very nice answer.i'm using visual studio 2013.

Comment: Then your compiler is Microsoft's `cl.exe`, it is a very common compiler and it is very unlikely that the problem comes from here. Again, did you do the search from the good module?

Comment: here i took a snapshot http://i.imgur.com/9GsvD32.png. actually it shows something like `ntdll` .i think i'm doing something wrong .could you explain little about ntdll

Comment: That's it. `Ntdll` is a system layer, it's from here that your program's entry point will be called. You have to find that entry point by executing your program step by step (`Step Over`). When you find it, just `Step into` and then do your search.  http://i.imgur.com/N1IUVt7.png

Comment: so how i find entry point? by lookng at text <module entry point> ?

Comment: Yes by executing step by step, and to the left of `<module entry point>` you'll find your exe name.

Comment: eventually i can see "password " texts .tnx

Comment: At this line, you have to `Step into`. Then, do your search.

Comment: don't need press f7 or f8 to go to your code. Just press Alt+e and then double click on your code and after search